# IOS - Streaming and Downloading an Audio File

Tags: ios, streaming, download

I am currently making an app that is capable of streaming a music file. The problem is, our client wants it that while we are streaming an audio file, the streamed bytes will also be saved in the local storage. Which means that the streamed audio file will also be saved on the device's storage. For example I have this m4a file streamed, when the user stops streaming the audio file, the streamed music file will be saved in the device's local storage for future use.

Is this possible? If it is, what library should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible use AVFoundation framework for this and play your audio.

First drag AVFoundation framework from built phase section then import like this  `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Then declare `AVAudioPlayer` in .h file of your view controller instance like this

```
AVAudioPlayer *myAudioPlayer;
```

In view controller.m put this code

```
NSURL *fileURL = // your url.   
myAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
myAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
[myAudioPlayer play];
```

Via this way you are able to play audio in your iOS device.hope it will help your for playing audio

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.  The question was to play a remote URL (not a local file URL) and while playing save the data into a local file.  This answer appears to show how to play a local file URL, and could easily be adapted to a remove URL, but doesn't seem to provide any way of saving the data that's downloaded.  Is there a way of creating an `AVAudioPlayer` that calls a user callback to get the file data, rather than downloading the file itself?  That would make implementing this pretty simple.